Identifying wall material and related concerns
I recently bought an apartment and since it has really ugly wallpaper, I am trying to replace it.
I have peeled back the wallpaper in some spots expecting to see a white plaster wall, but instead saw this:

Does anyone know what type of material this is and if there are any risks with removing the wallpaper in question, and painting the wall after (with use of primer)?
I am the worst DIYer this board has ever seen so hence the question out of abundance of caution.

Common construction techniques vary by locale. Where in the world are you located?

Guessing from the picture, this wall was painted, papered, and painted again. I have never in my life seen a house that wallpapered properly. You can also tell because you can usually remove huge swaths of paper at a time, looking exactly like your picture. The different "color" layers may be the inside of the paper - a light brown, prior wall papers (yes some paper over paper), the adhesive, or paint. Don't think you've made it down to bare wall.
I don't even need to know the age of the house to say lead precautions is the chief concern. You can buy a test kit. When you test, it's important to get a core sample. You have to cut a gouge from the wall to access many layers of material, so choose an inconspicuous spot like behind an outlet plate. If at any point you're not comfortable, stop. A professional lead abatement is an unbelievably expensive endeavor. Lead abatement would basically be a "to-the-studs" renovation, turns a $1,000 job into a $20,000 one.
This is unsolicited advice, but I did not use lead abatement. My process was: I taped off all vents and gaps, opened windows with a fan and an air filter, and taped plastic down on the floor, and I donned tyvek and a P100 mask. If I had a larger budget I would have rented a negative air machine HEPA filter. I pulled the paper, washed off the adhesive with TSP solution, sanded down the wall, and then washed down the whole space and deposed the material at a toxic waste facility. I then painted the plaster with proper technique - screwing down some failing sections, applying a skimcoat, then priming, sanding and two layers of top coat. The result was fantastic.
